# Handling big data with angular-meteor and handsontable

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor, handsontable, angular-meteor

So, here's the situation:
I am creating a web app in angular-meteor ( which is a project that allows to create meteor apps in angular ). The app is a little bit like a database app. So first I have collections:

```
{ _id: '12jbhb1', name: 'users' }
```

Then these collections have columns:

```
{ _id: '23jjh1j23', name: 'Full Name', collectionId: '12jbhb1' }
```

Lastly I have records for each collection:

```
{ _id: '2321hwerueh', collectionId: '12jbhb1', data: { '23jjh1j23': 'John Doe' } }
{ _id: '23f3rueh', collectionId: '12jbhb1', data: { '23jjh1j23': 'Jane Doe' } }
{ _id: '23f3r123eh', collectionId: '12jbhb1', data: { '23jjh1j23': 'Mike Doe' } }
```

NOTE: data's keys corresponds to the columnId

But the requirement is to implement handsontable. But handsontable won't expect data like this. So, I would have to encode it to work with hansontable but once I encode it in this way and someone edits any cell I would again have to decode it. The encoding part is done but I can't decode it. Can somebody help me. If somebody wants I can show how I encode it but it would be best if somebody can show me how he/she would go about encoding and decoding this mongo data for hansontable because this is my first project with handsontable. Please help me!

Comment: why don't you use the data, create a new object, and whenever you want to save it to your DB, encode it, rather than go through the process ever time? This way you would only need to do it once.

Comment: @ZekeDroid I didn't get it! What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: You make a call to your DB, process (decode) your data, and save it to some array or map. You use this as your mutable object with Handsontable. When you are ready to Save to the DB, you encode the data whatever way you like.

Comment: You are right! I tried that approach it didn't work because once I DECODE the data I don't have references left to which collection and column is which. I mean I wouldn't have any collectionId or columnId or RowId etc. left.

Comment: you could keep it, yes, and just not use it as a column. What I do is make the last element of each row be the SQL id (in your case whatever ID you need) and then never display this column in HOT